# How to correctly specify a list in java

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse Juno and Java.

I want to create a list and then store that list in another list so I can pass the list of lists to the server side. I have tried:

```
ArrayList<T> listAccountAndCubs = new ArrayList<Comparable>();
listAccountAndCubs.add(accountId);
listAccountAndCubs.add(sqlDateArchived);
```

However, I can not get the values "T" and "Comparable" correct. I tried "String" however that does not work for storing the date.

Once the above is correct how do I set up the list to contain "listAccountAndCubs"?

Thanks for any assistance,

Glyn

Comment: `ArrayList<Comparable> listAccountAndCubs = new ArrayList<Comparable>();` And a good beginner book/tutorial will solve your problems.

Comment: @Thihara `List<Comparable> listAccountAndCubs` is quite better than `ArrayList<Comparable> listAccountAndCubs` ;)

Comment: You should use `List<Comparable> listAccountAndCubs`  I think so.

Comment: @m0skit0 Yes agreed. I just pasted his code and corrected it. Didn't really thought about it.

Comment: Hi Thihara, thank you for your reply. I have already tried "Comparable" and have the warning "Comparable is a raw type. Reference to generic type Comparable<T> should be parameterized" which is why I tried "T". The quick fixed are "Infer Generic Type Arguments" [this does not work], "Add SuppressWarnings 'rawtypes' to 'listAccountAndCubs'" and "Add SuppressWarnings 'rawtypes' to 'onClick()'. I guess I will just suppress the warning. Regards, Glyn.

Comment: Hi Thihara,I tried List<Comparable> listAccountAndCubs = new List<Comparable>(); and got an error "Cannot instantiate the type List<Comparable>". Then I read below - it should be  List<Comparable> listAccountAndCubs = new ArrayList<Comparable>(); which is, I believe what you meant. So thank you for this very good advice. Regards, Glyn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you crrectly you want to have a list of Strings, and store this in another list?

```
List<String> sl = new ArrayList<String>();
List<List<String>>sls = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
sls.add(sl);
sl.add("String 1");
```

The value "T" is just a placeholder for the type, as the list is a generic interface, which can take any arbitrary object.

If you want to create a list of unspecified types, you would use

```
List<?>list = new ArrayList<?>();
```

Then you can add untyped objects to it, but in your case this is not neccessary.

Instead you can of course also create a list of comparables. Like this:

```
List<Comparable<String>>list = new ArrayList<Comparable<String>>();
```

Comment: Hi Devolus, Thank you very much for your help. I ended up using List<Comparable> sl = new ArrayList<Comparable>();
List<List<Comparable>>sls = new ArrayList<List<Comparable>>(); as I have a date being stored. Regards, Glyn.

Comment: If you have a date, you might better usee, `Comparable<Date>`  or whatever datatype you use. It is preferably to specify the datatype, unless you really want to have mixed objects, because then the compiler can do typechecks, you don't need to cast and you wont get unneccessary warnings either.

Comment: Hi Devolus, I am using both string and date, as per my example, so I do need to use Comparable. Regards, Glyn.

Answer (score 4):

this is how you can create a list

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
```

this is how you can create list of list

```
List<List<Comparable>> listOfList = new ArrayList<List<Comparable>>();
listOfList.add(new ArrayList<Comparable>());
...
```

Comment: I think the first line should contain `new ArrayList` or something like that, as `List` is an `Interface`.

Comment: List is an interface you cannot instantiate it.

Comment: This post sure got some quick hate.

Comment: Thanks sanbhat, Dahaka, Mustafa.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want something like this

```
List<List<String>> listAccountAndCubs = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

I would recomment using Google Guava library to clean the syntax a bit

```
List<List<String>> listAccountAndCubs = Lists.newArrayList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<ArrayList<Comparable>> listAccountAndCubs = new ArrayList<>();
```

or

```
List<String> l1=new ArrayList<>();
List<List<String>> l2=new ArrayList<>();

l1.add("a");
l2.add(l1);
```